# Unsecure POST form on secure page

Tags: php, forms, post, https

I got a secure website and have a form which posts to an external website.
The website only works with http, gives an error when accessing through https (not found)
I asked the organization responsible for this external website to make it secure.
They said they will work on it. In the meantime I want to launch my website but the insecure post breaks secure page (homepage).

I already tried to redirect my own domain with a certificate to the external website but that doens't work with POST. It posts to a PHP file.

Is there any way I can make it look secure on my website?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to fool users into thinking they are sending data securely when in fact they are not. One would hope all browsers would do their best to prevent this. The best solution is to wait for the organisation to implement https.

Comment: this is called a mixed content policy. this is what you need to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

Comment: It's just ridiculous that they don't change that, I mean how hard is that :(

Thank you for your answers, I think I'll just wait and leave the secure indicator grey instead of green. Hope they will fix it eventuality.

Comment: @RemyvanGelderen Psst, there is a work around I do it sometimes when I encounter some of these browsers restrictions like "CORS" or mixed content.... you can configure a php file on your website that do all these requests freely by a network library e.g cURL and response to you with the response he gets from the target (like a little own proxy)

Comment: I tried that  but can't get it to work :(
I need to post the form data (field name 'pincode') and return the file.
Downloading the file is where I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0):

The external website implemented a secure connection on our request so this is solved. Thanks everyone.